# Open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with measure zero

Tags: measure-theory

> Is it possible to have a open unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ with measure zero?

I tried to generate something using the Cantor set, but couldn't find an example. Every open set is measurable by definition, but is there a set that would satisfy this condition?

Comment: An open set contains an open ball.

Comment: That I know, but how is that of help?

Comment: What's the measure of an open ball?

Comment: Is the measure of open ball defined? Wouldn't you have to have a cover for it?

Comment: An open set contains an open rectangle. Now use monotonicity of measures.

Comment: yes, if the empty set is one such set (and the only if you are referring to Lebesgue's measure)

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek: unless the open set is the empty set, that is.